# Using a LINQ query instead of a foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to convert this this piece of code to a LINQ query as LINQ is much quicker than a foreach.
I dont know how to go about doing it, can do basically simple LINQ queries.

What i am trying to do is get a specific field in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> fieldLayout = null;
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> dic in pageLayout)
{
    if (dic[ "FIELD" ].ToString() == "123")
    {
        fieldLayout = dic;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that Linq is quicker than foreach? Do you need to optimize this code?

Comment: LINQ is not faster or slower than for-each..

Comment: Yes i need to optimize the code

Comment: Why do you keep object, not string? Calling ToString() is not the best choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, LINQ is not faster than a foreach loop.

Here is the implementation:

```
Dictionary<string, object> fieldLayout = pageLayout.Where(x => x["FIELD"].ToString() == "123").FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even better:

```
Dictionary<string, object> fieldLayout = pageLayout.FirstOrDefault(x => x["FIELD"].ToString() == "123");
```

Comment: I'd recommend to leave only the 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

`fieldLayout = pageLayout.FirstOrDefault(dic => dic["FIELD"].ToString() == "213");`

Comment: Should be `dic["FIELD"].ToString()` like in the original code because the dictionary has values of type object. Otherwise you'd do a by-reference comparison which is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is hardly faster than `foreach`, but that's outside the scope here.

```
var fieldLayout = pageLayout.FirstOrDefault(pl => pl["FIELD"].ToString() == "123");
```